# perl - Resolve hostname and AP status from SNMP

Tags: perl, snmp

The idea is that the first get_table gets the AP status off a WLAN controller, then it uses get_request to get the AP's hostname as it's printing out the status table. The problem I'm having is the $ap_name comes back as an array, when I just want the single value.

```
my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
                        -hostname => "$hostaddr",
                        -community => "$community",
                        -timeout => "30",
                        -version => "2c",
                        -port => "161");

if (!defined($session)) {
        printf("ERROR: %s.\n", $error);
        exit 1;
}


my $ap_stat = $session->get_table( -baseoid => $ap_stat_oid );
my $ap_name = $session->get_table( -baseoid => $ap_name_oid);

if (! defined $ap_stat || ! defined $ap_name) {
    die "Failed to get OID '$ap_stat_oid': " . $session->error;
    $session->close();
}
my @ap_name_array;
foreach my $ap_name_key (keys %$ap_name) {
        push(@ap_name_array,$ap_name->{$ap_name_key});
}
my @ap_stat_array;
foreach my $ap_stat_key (keys %$ap_stat) {
        push(@ap_stat_array,$ap_stat->{$ap_stat_key});
}
```

Edit: I changed it up a bit but still can't figure out what's next. I think I want to store the print output's into arrays and then join them and print for the joined array but I'm not sure how.

Edit: Here's my desired output:

```
AP-01 = 1
AP-02 = 1
AP-03 = 2
AP-04 = 1
```

etc..

More edits: I got the values into an arrays, now I'm just trying to get the output right.

Comment: A reference to a hash is returned in blocking mode which contains the contents of the VarBindList. In non-blocking mode, a true value is returned when no error has occurred. In either mode, the undefined value is returned when an error has occurred. The error() method may be used to determine the cause of the failure.

Comment: I read that too, but I need the get_table in non-blocking. Do I have to open another session just for the AP name?

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual OIDs you're using.

Comment: Hello again, I'm using .1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.3 (bsnAPName) and .1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.6 (bsnAPOperationStatus). I also updated the code and used push() to create two arrays

Comment: Also I used my 
`%result;
@result{@ap_name_array} = @ap_stat_array;
print Dumper %result;`

And they're all lined up

Comment: Why are you making two separate calls to `get_table`? bsnAPName and bsnAPOperationStatus are both in the same table (bsnAPTable); you should be able to make a single `get_table` request with that OID.

Comment: I'm trying to make it pretty universal. These OID's are in the same table on the host I'm testing against but we have cisco, brocade, and meru controllers. The goal was to make one plugin that could gather the statuses on all of them given the correct oid's and they're not all in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise); from [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=966310)

```
if (! defined $ap_stat || ! defined $ap_name) {
    die "Failed to get OID '$ap_stat_oid': " . $session->error;
    $session->close();
}
my @ap_name_array;
foreach my $ap_name_key (keys %$ap_name) {
        push(@ap_name_array,$ap_name->{$ap_name_key});
}
my @ap_stat_array;
foreach my $ap_stat_key (keys %$ap_stat) {
        push(@ap_stat_array,$ap_stat->{$ap_stat_key});
}

print pairwise { "$a = $b\n" } @ap_name_array, @ap_stat_array;
```

Beat you to it @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thanks anyways!